Extrusion for non-uniform meshes in GMSH
I'm new to GMSH and having some trouble with creating a 3D mesh from a surface extrusion.
Here’s the situation: I have a 2D surface with non-uniform element sizes. Near the walls, the elements are much smaller—about 20 times smaller than those further away. When I extrude this surface to create a 3D mesh, I have the option to set the number of layers. From what I understand, the number of layers will control the element size in the third dimension, right?
The problem is, if I choose a number of layers that matches the size of the larger elements (away from the walls), the aspect ratio of the smaller elements (near the walls) gets distorted. But if I adjust for the smaller elements, the larger ones end up being too thin and stretched.
Is there a way in GMSH to control the extrusion size in the third dimension in a way that avoids messing up the aspect ratios? Any suggestions on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated!.
Thanks in advance

This is really a gmsh question. You should ask it on the gmsh forums.

That said: What is it you want to happen? You clearly say that the layer-by-layer approach does not work either at the boundary or in the interior, but you don't say what it is you want to happen instead. The way I interpret your question is that you don't actually want to "extrude", because extruding is generally understood to be layers of a fixed extension in the third dimension. I think what you seem to want is simply a non-uniform 3d mesh, rather than an extruded 2d mesh.

I will add that there are often good reasons to have cells with large aspect regions in the near-boundary region.
